# Angular UI Bootstrap Timepicker - value assignment issue with 24hr times

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The timepicker is not handling 24hr time assignment correctly. For e.g.

```
<timepicker ng-model="$time" hour-step="1" minute-step="1" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
```

When I do: `$scope.$time = "2012-04-23T18:25:43Z"`, the timepicker is updated to `06:25 AM`. It should be `06:25 PM`.

Even if I set `show-meridian="false"`, it's still showing `06:25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Z" in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format stands for UTC.  Therefore, depending on the current local timezone offset, your results may vary.

> For example, I am located on the east coast in the US.  When daylight
>   savings is being observed here, my timezone offset is UTC−04:00,
>   otherwise it is UTC-05:00.  For me, the result of the time portion of
>   2012-04-23T18:25:43Z in meridian is either:  **2:25 PM** or **1:25 PM**
>   depending on the time of year.

Check the snippet below to see the representation of the UTC value versus the locale-specific timepicker value that accounts for your timezone offset:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.time = '2012-04-23T18:25:43Z';
  
}]);
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">

  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>{{time}}</h3>
    <timepicker ng-model="time" show-meridian="true"></timepicker>
    <p>Your local timezone offset is: <strong> UTC {{time | date:'Z'}}</strong></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ok, that didn't look like it'll make a difference, and guess what, it didn't :)

Comment: I don't know what you expect the output to be, but it does work.  If you run the code snippet, it correctly outputs the time in meridian based on the UTC time for 18:25:43.  That means that if, for example, you are in the US EDT it will show: 2:25 PM (which is -4 hours from UTC currently during daylight savings).

Comment: The Z stands for UTC in ISO formats.  You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: ok got you now. In that case there is no need to do `new Date('2012-04-23T18:25:43Z')` at all, `"2012-04-23T18:25:43Z"` works exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, the reason I made that recommendation is that in your question, you stated that you were getting 6:25 AM as your results.  That seemed unlikely since AFAIK there are no populated places corresponding to -12HR UTC.  It only occurred to me now that you could be in +12 (e.g., NZ) and might not notice the date shift if you're only displaying a timepicker.  I'll update the answer for others in the future.

Comment: Yes... sucks to be in NZ and don't know much about UTC time format :)